# express bodyParser blocking event loop

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

i have an app which takes in json requests. these json requests can be up to 200k.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.time("start2")
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '5mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(cors());
app.enable('trust proxy');


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.timeEnd("start2")
    next();
});
```

and what gets printed to the console is

```
start2: 591ms
```

am i correct in assuming parsing the json body of the request blocked the event loop for 591 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't assume that. It takes about 600ms in between your `console` calls, but only some of that will be taken up by `body-parser` parsing the JSON data (which *will* block the event loop). Still, parsing 200K of JSON is not something that will take that much time. On my Mac, it takes about 50ms to parse a 3MB JSON file.

I think that most of those 591ms will actually be spent *reading* the request body (which is non-blocking).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I took a look through here https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js#L91 and would it be the read() which is where the most of the 591ms is taking place in a non event loop blocking way?

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess. You can edit the files in `./node_modules/body-parser` of your project to add some additional timers and see if that's actually correct :-)

Comment: That looks right. Any thoughts as to why , for similar requests, sometimes it takes a few ms and others, 500+ ms? I'm not seeing any other requests happening at this time.

Comment: @MatthewChung it depends on how you're testing, really. If client and server aren't running in the same hardware, network latency starts to play a role. Also, it depends on how busy the server and/or client servers are.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're correct in assuming that parsing the json body took 591ms, but it did not necessarily block the event loop for that amount of time.  The middleware in Express (and Connect under the hood) is intentionally sequential, but it should not block the event loop in most cases.  It *can* block the event loop, depending on how you write it, but the time you have is just a measure of how long it took each middleware to call `next()`